# How to fill in professional experience using online-system?

Tags: resume, job-search, applications

I'm applying for a job, where on the online-system, I'm asked to fill in my professional experience in series of drop-down selection. Please see attached screenshot.[image]

What gets me confused that I have total 5 yrs of experience, now from the options it seems that when  I add the years it take me more then 5 years which is odd.

Infact, the top three items I have achieved within my 4 years working in single company. For e.g **years of working in trending/threat analysis reporting** if  I put **more than 1 year but less than 2 year experience** it means Ii have been doing first 2 simultaneously.

Can someone guide me with correct way of filling this form? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I would not worry about the total number of years of experience adding up to more than the length of your career. Most projects involve multiple skills, so it's normal for that to happen. And it will be clear from other parts of the form exactly how long your career has been, so no one could think you're trying to hide something.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of specific skills years will not equal your total number of worked years.  In IT we know that people are learning and using several tools at the same time.    To simplify.  An office manager may have 7 years of experience. (Total). She had 7 years using word, 4 years using PowerPoint, 6 years using excel and 1 year using access.    The system is trying to rank your experience in particular areas to determine if you have the level needed for their opening